# In python how can I add a special case to a regex function?

Tags: python, regex

Say for example I want to remove the following strings from a string:

```
remove = ['\\u266a','\\n']
```

And I have regex like this:

```
string = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', string)
```

How can I add "remove" to my regex function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can always remove them before doing the regex like so:

```
remove = ['\\u266a','\\n']

for substr in remove:
    string = string.replace(substr, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for a special case. Just call re.sub in a loop for each member of your remove list.